# Aren't Monads essentially just "conceptual" sugar?

Tags: haskell, monads

Let's assume we allow **two** types of functions in Haskell:

- strictly pure (as usual)
- potentially non-pure (procedures)

The distinction would be made f.x. by declaring that a dot (".") as first letter of a function name declares it as a non-pure procedure.

And further we would set the rules:

- pure functions may be called by pure and non-pure functions
- non-pure functions may only be called by non-pure functions
- **and**: non-pure functions may be programmed imperatively

With this syntactical sugar and specifications at hand - would there still be a need for Monads? Is there anything Monads could do which above rule set would not allow?

B/c as I came to understand Monads - this is exactly their purpose. Just that very smart people managed to achieve this purely by means of functional methods with a cathegory theoretical tool set at hand.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-pure functions may be programmed imperatively"?

Comment: @DonStewart 99% he means `do` notation.

Comment: @DonStewart: that within the procedure an expression or statement may be individually evaluated, its value stored in a variable and the variable used in a following expression or statement - something like that

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: that's pretty much what I am referring to

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569852/how-does-the-monad-based-io-design-of-haskell-contrasts-with-one-based-on-tagg .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## No.

Monads have nothing to do with purity or impurity in principle. It just so happens that `IO` models impure code nicely, but `Monad` class can be used perfectly right for instances like `State` or `Maybe`, which are absolutely pure.

Monads also  allow expressing complex *context hierarchies* (as I choose to call them) in a very explicit way. "pure/impure" isn't the only division you might want to make. Consider `authorized`/`unauthorized`, for example. The list of possible uses goes on and on... I'd encourage you to look at other commonly used instances, like `ST`, `STM`, `RWS`, "restricted IO" and friends to get a better understanding of the possibilities.

Soon enough you'll start making your own monads, tailored to the problem at hand.

Comment: I just want to emphasize the "NO" even more.  Monads allow you to do a lot more than just adding impure functions would.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to give you some extra support. :)

Comment: I guess I just have to gain more in depth experience with Monads to understand your answer - nonetheless maybe there is a simplified, yet concrete example to clarify your point? The maybe Monad as I understood it is mostly just an abbreviation for a if-expression and state is the result of non-purity - as far as I understand.

Comment: @Raffael I could give you an example that uses one of the pure instances, but it would be essentially copying it from its manual. I can point you to reading more directly, though. [*Three Useful Monads*](http://adit.io/posts/2013-06-10-three-useful-monads.html) explains Reader, Writer and State. [*A Fistful of Monads*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads) from LYAH shows basic principles and explores the use of `Maybe`. After reading and understanding those, you should see that your original "pure/impure" distinction was very narrow.

Comment: @Raffael `State` isn't impure (it's mostly a wrapper for `(a -> a)` functions), and `Maybe` is indeed a bit similar to an "if"-chain, but in a much nicer form in its monadic appearance. Again, refer to the articles for more detailed-explanations.

Comment: Adding to this, it makes entirely sure that actions occur in in the order intended.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Good that you pointed out that state isn't impure per se. The line of reasoning is often: state requires side effects which are impure (non referentially transparent), i.e. state ==> impure. On the other hand, whether you loose referential transparency depends on how you model state.

Answer (score 11):

> B/c as I came to understand Monads - this is exactly their purpose.

Monads in their full generality have nothing to do with purity/impurity or imperative sequencing. So **no**, monads are most certainly not conceptual sugar for effect encapsulation if I understood your question.

Consider that overwhelmingly most of the monads in the Prelude: `List`, `Reader`, `State`, `Cont`, `Either`, `(->)` have nothing to do with effects or IO. It's a very common misconception to assume that IO is the "canonical" monad, while in fact it's really a degenerate case.

Answer (score 4):

> B/c as I came to understand Monads - this is exactly their purpose.

This: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/monads.html#monads was the first paper on monads in Haskell:

> Category theorists invented monads in the 1960's to concisely express certain aspects of universal algebra.

So right away you can see that monads have nothing to do with "pure" / "impure" computations.  The most common monad (in the world!) is `Maybe`:

```
data Maybe a
  = Nothing
  | Just a

instance Monad Maybe where
    return = Just
    Nothing >>= f = Nothing
    Just x >>= f = f x
```

The monad is the four-tuple `(Maybe, liftM, return, join)`, where:

```
liftM :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
liftM f mb = mb >>= return . f

join :: Maybe (Maybe a) -> Maybe a
join Nothing = Nothing
join (Just mb) = mb
```

Note that `liftM` takes a *non-`Maybe`* function (not pure!) and applies it to a `Maybe`, while `join` takes a two-level `Maybe` and simplifies it to a single layer (so `Just` in the result comes from having two layers of `Just`:

```
join (Just (Just x)) = Just x
```

while `Nothing` in the result can come from a `Nothing` at either layer:

```
join Nothing = Nothing
join (Just Nothing) = Nothing
```

).  We can translate these terms as follows:

- `Maybe`: a value that may or may not be present.
- `liftM`: apply this function to the value if present, otherwise do nothing.
- `return`: take this value that is present and inject it into the extra structure of a `Maybe`.
- `join`: take a (value that may or may not be present) that may or may not be present and erase the distinction between the two layers of 'may or may not be present'.

Now, `Maybe` is a perfectly suitable data type.  In scripting languages, it's expressed just by using `undef` or the equivalent to express `Nothing`, and representing `Just x` the same way as `x`.  In C/C++, it's expressed by using a pointer type `t*`, and allowing the pointer to be `NULL`.  In Scala, there's an explicit container type: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option .  So you can't say "oh, that's just exceptions" because languages with exceptions still want to be able to express 'no value here' without throwing an exception, and then apply functions if the value is there (which is why Scala's Option type has a `foreach` method).  But 'apply this function if the value is there' is precisely what `Maybe`'s `>>=` does!  So it's a very useful operation.

You'll notice that C and the scripting languages don't generally allow the distinction between `Nothing` and `Just Nothing` to be made --- a value is either present or not.  In a functional language --- like Haskell --- it's interesting to allow both versions, which is why we need `join` to erase that distinction when we're done with it.  (And, mathematically, it's nicer to define `>>=` in terms of `liftM` and `join` than the other way around).

Incidentally, to clear up the common mis-conception about Haskell and IO: GHC's implementation of IO wrappers up the side-effectfulness of GHC's implementation of I/O.  Even that is a terrible design decision of GHC --- imperative (which is different than impure!) I/O can be modeled monadically without impurity at any level of the system.  You don't need side effects (at any layer of the system) to do I/O!

Comment: In C++, hopefully we'll see a much more elegant `std::optional`. Nullability of pointers in C++, C and Java has always been a source of stupid errors.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz 30 seconds googling suggests `std::optional` isn't actually standardized yet (and that it lacks equivalents of `liftM` and `>>=`, which would probably be good additions).

Comment: Oh, `optional` isn't going to be a Monad; I was just referring to your pointer remark.

Comment: I know, I'm just trying to make sure I understand myself before I try clarifying my answer.