# How does the "monad-based IO" design of Haskell contrasts with one based on tagging pure/impure code?

Tags: haskell

The IO Monad is known to separate pure from impure code in Haskell, such that a signature like `f :: ... -> IO ?` represents an action with side-effects, otherwise it is a pure function.

In addition, monads are used in Haskell as a purely functional mechanism to sequence actions, which otherwise could be unexpectedly reordered by a compiler that is designed to deal with only pure functions.

The trouble with a design around monads is that they seem hard to understand to many, perhaps including myself, so I wonder if they are the best way to separate the pure from impure code in software development.

I suppose that if we had a language where all primitives would be tagged as pure and impure, a compiler could easily infer the purity of any function using the primitives directly or indirectly, which would be a much simpler design. Such compiler would then know which parts of the code could be reordered because they are pure, or some order would be necessary due to the presence of side-effects.

So, my question is:

What are the advantages/disadvantages of "monad-based IO" design in comparison to one based on tagging pure/impure primitives in the language, that I described above?

Comment: The power of monads extends far beyond knowing what is and is not pure.  Keep trying, you'll get it.

Comment: A clear advantage is that using monads gives you a clear abstraction to use the same functions across many different monads.  Just look at all the functions in `Control.Monad` and elsewhere, there are dozens of combinators that work with `Monad m => ...`, regardless of which monad it is.  This lets you reuse powerful tools in a lot of cases.

Comment: Your question appears to assume that the only point in separating pure things from impure ones is enabling the compiler to do more oprimisations. However, tracking side effects is useful not only just for the compiler, but also for the humans writing and reading code. Tracking side-effects with types gives us reliable and easily accessible information about their presence or absence, information which is extremely useful when structuring programs.

Comment: I've always found it more useful to look at what constitutes a monad (based on the type signature and the laws). Cute analogies like "it's kind of like containers" and "it's used for sequencing actions" work well for some particular instances, but aren't generally useful to understanding what's actually going on.

Comment: @Cubic I see monads as a way to process the sequence of functions in `a >> ... >> z` into whatever we need and finally `return ...` the result of such processing. What I am not getting is how such thing can be so powerfull as people say.

Comment: Because that's not what a monad is. `Monad` is a much higher level abstraction than just sequencing. "Just sequencing" is basically what you get from `Monoid` (or rather, `Semigroup` but that's not in base (yet)). If you want to stay within the sequencing analogy, a `Monad` is an `Applicative` functor with the ability to sequence and branch on previous 'results'.

Comment: @Cubic When I said to "process the sequence" I meant that the monad consumes `a >> b ... >> z` by this order, but it can process them internally at will and do whatever the monad was designed to do, for example, when calling `return` at the end of the `do` block. As such, the monad can be used to implement some processing strategy for the a, b, and zs. Isn't this what a monad is supposed to be used?

Comment: More information needed: you mention "some order would be necessary", but haven't specified how your implementation selects which order to use e.g.
`(print "World!", print "Hello, ")` or `(print "Hello, ", print "World!")` - a language like Haskell is *nonstrict*, so you cannot rely on syntactic ordering as you would for e.g. Standard ML.

Answer (score 4):

Haskell does something like this with the IO type. However the Haskell type system is more general. You can think of a monad as a declaration of the potential scope of side effects, so rather than having a binary pure/impure flag you can have a much more sophisticated system.

Of course its a myth that Haskell monads are about "impurity". IO is a bit of a special case of course, but all the other monads are written in Haskell with a perfectly pure implementation of "bind". (Well, maybe ST and STM need a bit of magic from the run-time system for efficiency, but they *could* be written in Haskell).

Comment: "Its a myth that Haskell monads are about impurity" is a very important remark. `Monad` is a very general and abstract (which makes it a little tricky to grasp at first) but ultimately quite simple interface. IO just happens to be one of its many use cases.